# Reverse DNS Resolution - No PTR Record found

Tags: cpanel

My mail server is google apps(using CPANEL), and when I test my domain with MX lookup it gives me these errors:

Reverse DNS Resolution - No PTR Record found, 
Name Servers are on the Same Subnet, 
Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

How can I fix these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google App for email service, you do not need to worry about PTR record for Google's MX records.